# Pivot table strings grouping under pivot column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

```
JOB        ENAME
--------  ----------
ANALYST    SCOTT
ANALYST    FORD
CLERK      SMITH
CLERK      ADAMS
CLERK      MILLER
CLERK      JAMES
MANAGER    JONES
MANAGER    CLARK
MANAGER    BLAKE
PRESIDENT  KING
SALESMAN   ALLEN
SALESMAN   MARTIN
SALESMAN   TURNER
SALESMAN   WARD
```

I would like to format the result set such that each job gets its own column:

```
CLERKS  ANALYSTS  MGRS   PREZ  SALES
------  --------  -----  ----  ------
MILLER  FORD      CLARK  KING  TURNER
JAMES   SCOTT     BLAKE        MARTIN
ADAMS             JONES        WARD
SMITH
```

I tried

```
SELECT ANALYST, CLERK, MANAGER, PRESIDENT, SALESMAN from
(
  SELECT ename, job from emp
) as st
pivot
(
  SELECT ename
  FOR job in (ANALYST, CLERK, MANAGER, PRESIDENT, SALESMAN)
) as pivottable
```

I'm getting these errors

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.*

How to use pivot to group strings under pivot column?

Answer (score 22):

When you are using the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function, you are required to use an aggregate function.  The syntax of a `PIVOT` is:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>
FROM
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)
    AS <alias for the source query>
PIVOT
(
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
FOR
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
    ... [last pivoted column])
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

With a string, you will need to use either the `MIN()` or `MAX()` aggregate function. The problem that you will run into is that these functions will return only one value for each column.

So in order to get the `PIVOT` to work, you will need to provide a distinct value that will keep the rows separate during the `GROUP BY`.

For your example, you can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ANALYST, CLERK, MANAGER, PRESIDENT, SALESMAN 
from
(
  SELECT ename, job,
    row_number() over(partition by job order by ename) rn
  from emp
) as st
pivot
(
  max(ename)
  FOR job in (ANALYST, CLERK, MANAGER, PRESIDENT, SALESMAN)
) as pivottable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/143e4/2).

The `row_number()` creates a distinct value that is assigned to each row in the `job`, when you apply the aggregate function and the `GROUP BY` in the `PIVOT` you will still get separate rows.

Comment: What a wonderful solution. Thank you so much Taryn.