# SQL to transpose table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Looking for a simple way to kind-of transpose a table to be able to further analyze data in software with no DB capabilities.

Table:

```
Id  testdate partid testid
1  2-13-2014  45  58
2  2-23-2014  45  2
```

I want to extract a table from this that puts testid in the column name and date in its fields, thus looks like this:

```
partid  test-1  test-2  test-3  ...  test-58  ...
45                   2-23-2014                        2-13-2014
```

There could be a few 100 testid's. I plan to expand the code to multiple columns per testid, eg: test-1-date test-1-result test-1-success.

Prefer common SQL, but if it has to be specific I'd be MS SQL server.

Comment: Unless you have the list of all the tests in advance, you have to do this using dynamic SQL.  There is no such thing as a "variable" column name.

Comment: Is using only SQL mandatory? I suggest you to copy the tables  in excel and transpose them there.

Comment: Try using a Pivot in sql like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618316/how-to-create-a-pivot-query-in-sql-server-without-aggregate-function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transposing a table in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429442/transposing-a-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it, its "PIVOT" that I needed. When searching PIVOT there are many questions and answers on this site.

One thing that is different in my case compared with most other PIVOT examples is that I try to aggregate strings rather than numbers. (Think of the date field as a string)

Specifically helpful were:

[How to create a pivot query in sql server without aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618316/how-to-create-a-pivot-query-in-sql-server-without-aggregate-function)

[Get ROWS as COLUMNS (SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in mssql when columns are string data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976585/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-mssql-when-columns-are-string-data-type)

[Pivot table strings grouping under pivot column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337214/pivot-table-strings-grouping-under-pivot-column)